# Use Firebase and stamplay together. So I can still use Firebase Authorization and Stamplay Stripe

Tags: angularjs, firebase, stripe-payments, stamplay

So I built an App using Firebase as backend. Now I need to use Stripe to charge use and send payment (or PayPal, whichever works). And I google around solutions. Most of them do require a backend with Node.js. But that defeat the purpose of using Firebase at the first place. I use Firebase b/c I do not want to build an backend with Node.js. 
Then I heard stamplay. I do the same thing as Firebase but also provide out of the box integration with Stripe (and Mailchimp!). 
I do not want to change my app and keep using Firebase Authorization, managing users and store most of the data in Firebase. But come to dealing with payment, I want to use stamplay to connect with Stripe. But I do not where to start. So far, seem like the only way to use stamplay stripe (with AngularJS) is to use stamplay user Authorization, create user in stamplay and then use Stripe task - ditching Firebase completely. Can someone point me in the right direction use both these amazing services together - stamplay for APIs and Firebase for everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Giuliano (stamplay co-founder) nice to emeet you. I understand that you want to leverage our Stripe integration while still keep using Firebase for auth and data storage. To be able to seamlessly charge end-users of your app we automatically tie each one of them to a stripe customer.

If you want to stick to Firebase auth you need to mirror, at least partially, your users. Everytime you have a new user signed up you can forward it to stamplay and use a task to create a stripe customer binded to it. Then you can move on to leverage our integration by collecting user's credit card information.

The overhead of this approach is that you need to care about a kind-of Single sign on across both Firebase and Stamplay auth. What is currently Firebase auth providing that we cannot cover?

Comment: Honestly IDK yet since I still have not successfully use stamplay on my Ionic mobile App b/c of permission issue on your end (open ticket). Is anyone running Ionic successfully use your JavaScript SDK?! But back to the issue, I can theoretically create a Stamplay user after user log in Firebase. But then we have 2 different sessions - one from Firebase and one from stamplay. How can I sync these together? What if stamplay session expired and firebase not and create payment error? I will def love a solution with a single sign on to auth both stamplay and firebase together. Is there one?

Comment: @HughHou were ever successful with this integration and stamplay?

Comment: Yes. I did. Reach out to Stamplay and they will help you out.